# Check existence of JSON nested attribute

Tags: json, ruby, validation

I need to test whether a nested attribute exists in a JSON object before doing something with it. How can I accomplish this?

I know I can test one level at the time but this seems crazy when is a complex data structure. (Ruby code)

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

require 'json'

json_string = '
    {
        "name" : "Matias",
        "age" : 31,
        "team" : {
            "name" : "Some team",
            "size" : 3
        }

    }
'

json_obj = JSON.parse(json_string)


puts json_obj['name'] if json_obj['fake']['name']
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Hash#dig` which will just return `nil` as soon as a key is not found:

```
json_obj.dig('fake', 'name')
```

I assume you are on a recent version of ruby (>= 2.3).

Documentation for `dig` here: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-dig

Comment: Added version info + link